# AS3 Click movieclip to change saturation

Tags: actionscript-3

I'm really new to flash and am struggling to find a way to do this: 
I want my movieclip (myMC) to start off with no saturation, and then when clicked, regain the saturation.

```
import fl.motion.MotionEvent;

var color:AdjustColor = new AdjustColor();

myMC.filters.saturation = -100;

color = new AdjustColor();
color.brightness = 20;
color.contrast = 20;
color.hue = 0;
color.saturation = -100;


myMC.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, mousedwn);
function mousedwn (event:MouseEvent):void{

myMC.filters = [colorFilter]

}
```

I can't seem to find anything online... Thanks to anyone who can help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this while searching google.

[Changing Saturation Level with AS3](http://www.actionscript.org/forums/showthread.php3?t=215303)


It uses `flash.filters.ColorMatrixFilter`, instead of a plugin that you have to download.

Answer (score 1):

A very simple way is to use TweenMax from http://www.greensock.com/tweenmax/

One line of code is all it takes.

TweenMax.to(mc, 1, {colorMatrixFilter:{amount:1, saturation:1}});

Try the Plugin Explorer about half way down the page. colorMatrixFilter.

Comment: ah thanks.. i'm trying to teach myself the way to do it without a plugin.